# Как сделать бэкап сайта, если на хостинге мало места

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, администрирование

Столкнулся с проблемой создания бэкапа сайта из-за того что на хостинге не достаточно места для его сохранения. Обычно чтобы сделать бэкап всех файлов сайта подключаюсь по ssh и делаю архив корневой директории сайта, например, zip -r backup.zip public_html, но когда на хостинге мало места так сделать невозможно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то сохранять архив сразу на локальный компьютер?

Comment: `$ ssh куда@то команда-выдающая-что-то-в-stdout > /путь/к/локальному/файлу`

Comment: А по ftp туда нельзя подключаться или ещё как-то именно к файлам? Забирать файлы к себе, а там уже паковать. Можно автоматизировать, наверное.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за помощь! По ftp можно, но это долго. Воспользуюсь наверно 1-м вариантом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsyn c- программа для UNIX-подобных систем, которая эффективно выполняет синхронизацию файлов и каталогов в двух местах (необязательно локальных) с минимизированием трафика, используя кодирование данных при необходимости. Важным отличием rsync от многих других программ/протоколов является то, что зеркалирование осуществляется одним потоком в каждом направлении (а не по одному или несколько потоков на каждый файл). rsync может копировать или отображать содержимое каталога и копировать файлы, опционально используя сжатие и рекурсию. rsync передаёт только изменения файлов, что отражается на производительности программы.

копирование из локального каталога в удалённый:

```
rsync -arv local/directory user@remote.server.address:/remote/directory/
```

копирование из удалённого каталога в локальный:

```
rsync -arv user@remote.server.address:/remote/data local/directory/
```

Можно добавить параметр `--progress` для отображения процентов.